# Magento 2 : Convert Attribute to Link

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, product-attribute

I'm trying to make some attributes in product info details to link, to attribute search page to help customers search.

If my attribute is Armani, when a person clicks Armani in product info details, new page will display all products that have the Armani attribute.

I just found online code but it's for an older version of Magento and it doesn't work on Magento 2.0 version, somewhere in attributes.phtml file.

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
<?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
if(!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
<?php if(preg_match("/classification|manufacturer/i",($this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label']))))) { ?>
<tr>
<th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
<?php $query = str_replace(' ', '+', trim($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']))); $query = str_replace('&amp;','%26', $query); ?>
<?php $base_url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>
<td class="data"><?php echo "<a href=\"" . $base_url . "catalogsearch/result/?q=" . $query . "\">" . $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) . "</a>"; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } else { ?>
<tr>
<th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
<td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So can anyone help me with code for newest version of Magento?

Thanks.